# Clarity custom filter error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular, filter, datagrid, clarity

I am getting this error message in clarity when using custom filter using example from:
https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.11/datagrid/custom-filtering

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
Error is coming the first line:

```
   <clr-dg-column *ngFor="let column of (gridData$ | async)?.columnDefs" [clrDgField]="'column.name'">
       {{ column.name }}
       <clr-dg-filter [clrDgFilter]="datagridFilter">
           <app-datagrid-filter #datagridFilter></app-datagrid-filter>
       </clr-dg-filter>
   </clr-dg-column>
```

If I remove #datagridFilter, error goes away, but the filter input does not show.

DatagridFilter is defined as:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, Input } from '@angular/core';

import {Filter} from "clarity-angular/data/datagrid/interfaces/filter";
import {Subject} from "rxjs/Subject";


@Component({
    selector: "app-datagrid-filter"
})
export class DatagridFilter implements Filter<any> {
    changes = new Subject<any>();
    constructor(public prop: any) {
        this.prop = prop;
    }
    isActive(): boolean {
        return true;
     }
    accepts(item: any):boolean {
        return true;
        //return item.indexOf(search) > -1 || item.filter(i => i.indexOf(search) > -1)[0]
    }
}
```

DatagridFilter is instantiated further in the parent component. snippet:

```
export class DatagridComponent implements OnInit {
  count: number = 10;
  gridData$: Observable<any>;
  reportAction$: Observable<any>;
  formDefinition$: any;
  totalRecords$: Observable<number>;
  selected: any = [];
  datagridFilter: any;

......
ngOnInit() {

......
    this.gridData$.subscribe(data => {
        this.datagridFilter = new DatagridFilter(data.columnDefs);
    });
...
```

Comment: Where do you assign gridData$?

Comment: <code>ngOnInit() {
        console.log("DatagridComponent => ngOnInit()");
        let p = this.gridUrl || '';
        const payload = new AppActions.LoadDatagridDefinitionAction(p);
        console.log(" => dispatch(" + JSON.stringify(payload, null, 2) + ")");
        this.store.dispatch(payload);
        this.gridData$ = this.store.select(App.getDatagridData).share();
        this.gridData$.subscribe(data => {
            console.log('gridData$ :: ', JSON.stringify(data, null,0));
             this.datagridFilter = new DatagridFilter(data.columnDefs);
        });

    }</code>

Comment: in the ngOnInit itself in DatagridComponent as observable: `this.gridData$ = this.store.select(App.getDatagridData).share();`